# Set device width and scale correctly on retina iPhone? css

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, css

I have a design built at the correct width of 640px. I want to set the pixel ratio so that I can write 10px when I mean 10px of a 640px width. I don't want to try to divide every value in half. Is this possible? Something like, `initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5`?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a toughie. Read this article on viewports from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the use of a media query within your CSS

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* iphone 4 Styles */
}
```